# Uglifier not running when `config.assets.debug = false`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, uglifyjs

In `config/environments/development.rb`, I have this setting:

```rb
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Now, when I have:

```rb
config.assets.debug = true
```

then I will get errors when uglifier fails, like this one:

[image]

This is what I want, because uglifier is used in our production environments, and we found that, if we do not use uglifier in dev as well, then errors like the one above would not be discovered in the dev environment, and would surface in higher environments instead.

My issue is that `config.assets.debug = true` makes the dev server suuuuuuper slow, as documented [here](https://artandlogic.com/2012/12/faster-rails-dev/), and when I set it to `false`, the uglifier checks don't seem to happen, and I miss the errors like the one in the screenshot above. I have tried adding:

```rb
config.assets.compress = true
```

But this doesn't seem to make a difference.

To summaraize:

```rb
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.debug = true
```

is too slow, but allows us to catch uglifier errors.

```rb
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.debug = false
```

is blazing fast, but *does not* catch uglifier errors. So my question is: how can I get uglifier to run with debug mode off, and still report errors?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you are trying to achieve here but if your question is about how to fix the above error then you will have to use uglifier like this `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)`

Comment: Thanks @MonithShah, in this case, I am not trying to fix errors like the one pictured in my post. Instead, I want to ensure that errors like the above are not silenced in the development stage when I set `config.assets.debug = false`. Currently, even if I have code that will cause an uglifier error **in production**, I will not see that error in development if I have `config.assets.debug = false`.